# run PHP in the main page in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I was able to run PHP in pages with the Insert PHP plugin, but I would need to use it in the main (blog articles) page, is there any way I can do this?

Comment: are u getting any error? issue? plz share

Comment: I don't get any errors, because I don't know where do I have to insert the php code to run in main page.

Comment: Is your wordpress set to show static page on Homepage or list of posts? Which template files you tried to edit inside themes folder? Can you provide URL?

Answer (score 0):

For that you don't need any plugin.

In your wordpress dashboard, Navigate to Appearance and then Editor.

There You'll see archives.php template. That is the file which is triggerred when you see list of articles on homepage.

Directly Edit your code in template files. Please take a backup of files before making any changes.

Comment: it doesn't work for me, I even deleted everything from the archives file and the page still loads the same, I have already checked that I have the same theme set.